# How do I pass the value of input fields on one html page to input fields on another html page using dojo

Tags: html, forms, dojo

I am trying to pass the values of input fields on one html page to another html page that has a form with input fields. How do I write the dojo or JavaScript code to accomplish this?

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="form2.html">
    First Name: <input id="tFName" name="tFName" type="text" tabindex="0" iclass="isCompleted" maxlength="50" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Last Name: <input id="tLName" name="tFName" type="text" tabindex="0" iclass="isCompleted" maxlength="50" />
    <br/>

    <input type='submit' value='Submit'/>

    </form>
```

here is form 2:

```
<form id="form">
    First Name: <input id="tFName" name="tFName" type="text" tabindex="0" iclass="isCompleted" maxlength="50" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Last Name: <input id="tLName" name="tFName" type="text" tabindex="0" iclass="isCompleted" maxlength="50" />
    <br/>

    <input type='submit' value='Save Your Name'/>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't simply send data from one `.html` page to another, with or without javascript.

A form `POST` causes the browser to send the form data to the server in the body of the `HTTP` request.  You must then run some code *on the server* to do something with that data, even if it's just setting it as the initial values of fields on a different .html page.

Comment: dijit.form (Dojo) may be used to embellish the form controls, but a POST should still work without any additional JS necessary